# how could I load a bitmap file in a video feed?

Tags: opengl, graphics, augmented-reality, bmp

I am using artoolkit to create an augmented reality based project.I can load vrml 3d objects in the video feed using openvrml.
Now I wanted to load a bitmap or any other image file like jpg,png etc file on the marker in the video feed.How do I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is using an [overlay](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/contexts.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Just make a VRML 'model' consisting of a single quad with a texture corresponding to your image file.  Your existing VRML machinery should take care of the rest.